# Js, не срабатывает click при зажатом touchstart

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

```
left.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) =>  {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  console.log('left')
})

left.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
console.log('left')
})

right.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) =>  {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('right')
})

right.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  console.log('right')
})

jump.addEventListener('click', (event) =>  {
    console.log('jump')
})
```

Есть квадратик, который бегает и прыгает по платформе, но при зажатом движении вправо или влево не срабатывает прыжок. Только отдельно прыгает. Ну мало ли с кодом напортачил, вставил консоль.логи для проверки, не срабатывает прыжок при зажатом беге. Подскажите, почему? И как это можно исправить?
https://mark1789.github.io/physics_v1/

Comment: что такое `left`, `right`, `jump`?

Comment: Это кнопки передвижения элемента.  https://mark1789.github.io/physics_v1/

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена заменой click на touchstart в jump. Но вопрос остаётся открытым.